# Temporarily silencing beep on Socket 7Xi barcode scanner

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I am using the Socket iOS SDK with the 7Xi scanner. The scanner is fast enough to register duplicate scans in quick succession if a user holds a barcode in front of the scanner when in stand mode. To handle this, I am simply removing my scan delegate when the first scan arrives, and not setting it again until I am ready for the next scan.

Of course, the scanner itself continues scanning. Is there some way to silence the beep while I am handling the scan, so that my users don't think the scan was correctly received when the app does not. It must be fast enough that I can reliably re-enable it within a second or so.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the issue is the barcode scanner scanning the same barcode if it's held in front of the scanner too long (duplicate) or you would like to "lock out" new scans (next item) until your application is done processing the last scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background

The scanner has three confirmation modes (device, sdk and app) which determines who is responsible for acknowledging a barcode was scanned. The default is device, which will acknowledge any successful scan (i.e. the barcode type is supported and the device successfully decoded the barcode).

### Solutions

#### Option 1

Currently, you remove the scan delegate, which doesn't prevent the scanner from scanning the next barcode; It only prevents your application from receiving the event notification. You provide ScanApiHelper with a timer routine that calls `doReceive` to check for new events and if it finds one it calls your delegate.

You could add a flag to your timer so that it will only call `doReceive` when you are ready to handle the next event.

There are two limitations to this approach. There will be a delay between the device acknowledgement and feedback from the application, if important feedback is provided, when a scan is held in the queue. Second, a queue is only suitable for handling a brief burst of activity, but your application will require downtime to catch back up.

### Option 2

**Caveat:** I'm not sure if this works in presentation mode

Switch the confirmation mode to app and have your application acknowledge the barcode after it is done processing. This has the benefit of essentially locking out the scanner (it won't beep, flash or vibrate for any scan) unless your application has received and handled the barcode.

The downside here is there is a small lag between the barcode being read and the scanner acknowledging it, when using app confirmation mode. Adding an additional delay while processing the data may not be the best user experience.